# Resolving a shared answer link to its topic title when inserted into Stack Overflow post

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks, sharing, short-links

When writing answers to common questions I tend to add links to existing answers to avoid duplicating the content too much. Please don't start on the issue of whether links are appropriate due to topic deletion and such.

When I use the **share button** to create a shareable URL to insert into the other answer, I don't get it resolved to show the topic title in the new answer:

> **This does not resolve**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055933/129130
>
> **This resolves**: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933`

Here is the last link resolved: [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933)

It would be nice if the share URL also resolves to the topic title when inserted into other Stack Overflow answers. And it would be nice if the URLs from other sites, such as serverfault.com resolved the same way.

And yes, I am aware that I can use the shared url, paste it into the browser and get the  resolvable url showing up in the address bar (which is what I do when inserting the links into answers).

Comment: Maybe because they extract the title from the url instead with the short version they need to execute a query, maybe it cost too much to resolve short version too

Comment: Should this be asked on [MSE]?

Comment: @Bergi It's on-topic here.

Comment: This works for short URLs for questions.

Comment: I guess it's related to the data structure used in SE. It's the same when you search posts in Data Explorer; questions have title, answers don't have title. When you use "Share" button, it directly use Answer post. When you copy a comment from an answer, somehow it refers to question in the URL with additional parameter to locate the comment.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno: They definitely do not extract the title from the URL.

Comment: BUMP for great justice, why is this not implemented yet? It should be nothing more than a simple join from the `answerId` back to the `questionId` and from there, getting the question's title...